# TSMC model for lt spice simulation

Tags: ltspice, nmos, pmos

From where to  download the tsmc model file for nmos(slow,fast,typical) and pmos (slow,fast,typical)?

Answer (score 3):

Foundry models are confidential and you can't get them without signing NDAs and being a large company or educational institution.

Use PTM models as they are free, open and contain corners for multiple nodes.
http://ptm.asu.edu/

Comment: It appears to me that there hasn't been any activity at the PTM site for over six years, and it looks like they just have "typical" models rather than models for the process corners. Can you clarify or correct me on that?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson OP never specified which node was needed. PTM has 130-32nm models and provides SS FF and nominal models. Go to Nano-CMOS tab on the left and follow the steps and see the output.

Comment: OK, I see. As long as the user knows what the best/worst statistics of the process should be then they can enter desired variations in a few parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The MOSIS design service can supply TSMC SPICE models as part of a complete design kit. Contact MOSIS at www.mosis.com. Whether or not MOSIS will give you the models depends on what kind of organization you represent (educational institutions get special consideration) and whether you want models for the newest processes or for older processes.

Comment: I could see many models in it bjt

Comment: I could see many models in it but cannot see anything like NMOS fast or NMOS typical. What is the exact keyword to be searched?

Comment: You will have to establish yourself as a MOSIS customer before you can get the models, they can't just be downloaded.